# Latest JDK 8 Build 40 is returning intermittent exception from Nashorn Engine

Tags: java-8, java, nashorn

I installed new JDK 1.8 build: 40 and now I am getting following exception **intermittently** from a valid javascript function, Any thought?

```
java version "1.8.0_40-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-ea-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b23, mixed mode)
```

Exception:

```
.....
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: function __noSuchMethod__() { [native code] } is not a constructor function in <eval> at line number 21
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:455)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:439)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:401)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:397)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:152)
at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
at com.nube.portal.engines.js.JsEngine.eval(JsEngine.java:101)
... 74 more

Caused by: <eval>:21 TypeError: function __noSuchMethod__() { [native code] } is not a constructor function
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.error(ECMAErrors.java:57)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:213)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:185)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:172)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.getBestConstructor(ScriptFunctionData.java:239)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.findNewMethod(ScriptFunction.java:474)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptObject.lookup(ScriptObject.java:1874)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.NashornLinker.getGuardedInvocation(NashornLinker.java:100)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.NashornLinker.getGuardedInvocation(NashornLinker.java:94)
at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.CompositeTypeBasedGuardingDynamicLinker.getGuardedInvocation(CompositeTypeBasedGuardingDynamicLinker.java:176)
at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.CompositeGuardingDynamicLinker.getGuardedInvocation(CompositeGuardingDynamicLinker.java:124)
at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.LinkerServicesImpl.getGuardedInvocation(LinkerServicesImpl.java:149)
at jdk.internal.dynalink.DynamicLinker.relink(DynamicLinker.java:233)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$9$134AAA$\^eval\_.L:6$http(<eval>:21)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$8$977AA$\^eval\_.L:6$get(<eval>:41)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$7$\^eval\_.:program(<eval>:1)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:636)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:229)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:387)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:437)
... 79 more
```

**Code** : This utility will help to make a rest service call.

```
(function (global, factory) {

factory(global.Rest = {});

}(this, function (rest) {

rest.http = function(url, request, method) {

    method = (method == null?"GET":method);

    if(request != undefined){
        for (var key in request) {
            if (request.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                url = url + key+"="+request[key] +"&";
            }               
        }
    }

    with (new JavaImporter(java.io, java.net)) {
        var is = new URL(url).openConnection();
        try {
            is.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            is.setRequestMethod(method);
            var reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(is.getInputStream()));
            var buf = '', line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buf += line;
            }
        } finally {
           reader.close();
        }
        return buf;
    }
};

rest.get = function(url, request){
    return JSON.parse(rest.http(url, request, "GET"));
};

}));
```

Now I am using Rest.get() to make a service call

```
var result = Rest.get("http://someurl?...");
```

This call works fine for sometime and start throwing exception after sometime.

Comment: You should probably report this bug... But if you seek help from SO (and from the persons you'll report the bug to), some sample code is always better!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

probably, this is JavaImporter's bug.

I was resolved it by not be using JavaImpoter.

Answer (score 0):

I used below piece of code to get rid of this exception :

```
if (typeof importClass != "function") 
{
  load("nashorn:mozilla_compat.js");
}
```

And instead of JavaImporter, I used importClass.